# Strongly typed dataset adapter update won't insert a new row

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a property that holds a strongly typed dataset row.
I've added an insert and update procedure to my dataset.
If I pass the adapter a row that already exists it successfully updates the information. However if I create a new row then it won't insert it to the database table. The exception is never getting thrown, and the int returned is always 0. No new row has been appended.

```
private MyDataset.MyDatasetGetDataRow _row;

private MyDataset.MyDatasetGetDataRow Rowa
{
    get { return _row; }
    set { _row = value; }
}

public void NewOne()
{    
    MyDatasetTableAdapters.MyDatasetGetDataTableAdapter adapter = new MyDatasetTableAdapters.MyDatasetGetDataTableAdapter();
    MyDataset.MyDatasetGetDataDataTable tbl = adapter.GetData(0, 0);
    MyDataset.MyDatasetGetDataRow row = tbl.NewMyDatasetGetDataRow();
    Rowa = row;    
}

public int Save()
{
    try
    {
       int a = -99;
       using (MyDatasetTableAdapters.MyDatasetGetDataTableAdapter adapter = new MyDatasetTableAdapters.MyDatasetGetDataTableAdapter())
       {
           a = adapter.Update(tbl);
       }
       return a;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw new Exception("Error: It didn't save. (" + ex.Message + ")");
    }
```

}

Comment: New one can't work.  For an adapter to work, it needs a text SQL statement.  You code doesn't have a SQL so Rowa/row will always be empty.  So the read isn't working so it is hard to tell if you wrote the data.

Comment: The adapter has a select, update and insert SQL statement attached to it through a connection to the database and a stored procedure. As I have mentioned an update to an existing row works, however a new one does not insert. Rowa has data and exists, it is not null and the update does not error, it just simply returns 0.

Comment: What???  A connection doesn't create SQL statements unless you do it in your c# code in a different method that you didn't post.

Comment: Thats the point of the adapter. The adapter contains the connection and it points to 3 stored procedures in the database. get, update and insert. Get and update work. Insert doesn't. But it returns 0. Are you trying to say that the likely cause is my insert procedure is wrong?

Comment: Who told you that?  An adapter requires you to add a text command.  If you have a Select command in the adapter the commandbuilder will automatically create the inset, delete, and update from the select.  But the adapter is dumb and only does what you program.

Comment: I have a select command. Can you provide me an example of how you tell the adapter to insert then please.

Comment: See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Row did not belong to a table and so the dataset did not know that the row had been newly added.